# Asynchronous Google Analytics not logging in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-analytics

The code I have in place is tracking visits from Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera Mini, but not IE.  I believe the problem to be a matter or loading order, scope, or possibly the code placement.  I am currently using the following:

In my `example.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

In my `example.js`:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-########-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Where UA numbers have been changed to protect the innocent :).

First option:
- Remove the `ga.js` from the `html` file
- Add the script injection code to the `example.js` file below the `_gaq.push` calls:

```
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Has anyone had any success with putting the tracking code inside a javascript file?  Or do I have to move all the tracking code to the `html` file using [the snippet](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html) from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you call ga.js using the simple script tag or using the function expression doesn't make much of a difference, at least not concerning the described problem. The function expression is, however, recommended as to not block the rest of the page from loading while ga.js is being loaded.

Why IE (specifically IE 7 and IE 8) don't log your visits has to do with the order of execution, as you have suspected.

> This function is named push so that an array can be used in the place of _gaq before Analytics has completely loaded. While Analytics is loading, commands will be pushed/queued onto the array. When Analytics finishes loading, it replaces the array with the _gaq object and executes all the queued commands. Subsequent calls to _gaq.push resolve to this function, which executes commands as they are pushed.

See http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi_gaq.html#_gaq.push

So according to documentation it shouldn't matter whether you populate the array first and load and execute ga.js afterwards, or load and execute ga.js first and then trigger the tracking methods afterwards.

And indeed, in all modern browsers it doesn't matter. But IE 7 / 8 behave differently. If the `push` method has been replaced, calling it to execute the tracking methods, such as `trackPageview`, doesn't do anything in IE 7 / 8.

So to answer you question:

Populate the array (or load `example.js`) first, and then load `ga.js`, preferrably using the function expression.

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
```

as does this:

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-########-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

as does this:

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-########-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
```

or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>

<script>
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

We've had similar issue, our problem was, that we had a twoletter domain. Once you set _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xx.com']); it was all solved and worked fine.

Comment: Our domain name is longer than 2 characters, so I don't think this will solve my problem.  Thanks.